# Problema com dois cliques - Função Javascript

Tags: javascript

Estou utilizando essa função simples para alterar CSS condicionalmente em Javascript:

```
function zoom(obj, icon, menu) {
  var el = document.getElementById(obj);
  var img = document.getElementById(icon);
  var men = document.getElementById(menu);
  var men2 = document.getElementById(menu + "2");
  if (el.style.width === "360px") {
    el.style.width = "500px";
    el.style.height = "308px";
    men.style.width = "500px";
    men2.style.width = "500px";
    if (el.style.width === "500px") {
      img.src = "img/icons/png/minimize1.png";
    }
  } else {
    el.style.width = "360px";
    el.style.height = "222px";
    men.style.width = "360px";
    men2.style.width = "360px";
    if (el.style.width === "360px") {
      img.src = "img/icons/png/expand.png";
    }
  }
}
```

Ela é utilizada para alterar o tamanho de 3 elementos com Id's diferentes.

Mas quando utilizo a função em um link:

```
<a href="javascript:zoom('exemplo','exemplo2','exemplo3');">Chama função</a>
```

A função só é aplicada no segundo clique, depois disso funciona corretamente no primeiro clique. Por que isso acontece?

Comment: já tentou <a href="#" onclick="zoom('exemplo','examplo2','examplo3');">Chama função</a>?

Comment: Sim, mas obtenho o mesmo resultado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tudo funciona bem, entretanto, o fluxo condicional me parece fora da lógica que você quer.

No seguinte fragmento, você verifica se a largura de `el` é **360px**:

> ```
>  if (el.style.width === "360px") { }
> ```

Se a largura for exatamente 360px, então você declara uma nova largura para tal:

> ```
>  el.style.width = "500px";
> ```

Então, num segundo clique, a largura já não é mais `360px`, mas sim `500px`, o que o faz cair no `else`.

Note que você tem um conflito de condicional, onde você possui este `if`:

> ```
>  if (el.style.width == "500px") { }
> ```

dentro deste:

> ```
>  if (el.style.width === "360px") { }
> ```

**O que isso significa?**

Ou a largura é 500px ou é 360px – o mesmo elemento não tem como lidar com dois tamanhos simultaneamente; no fim das contas, isso é ilógico – não faz qualquer sentido.

Com a sua lógica, podemos representar o seu cenário com [este jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qGbw6/). Há a diferença orgânica de execução da sua função através de um listener, mas de resto mantenho tudo igual.

Não sei exatamente qual o seu objetivo ou qual o resultado que você quer chegar, mas não há nenhum problema técnico aí, apenas lógico ou conceitual. Se a minha resposta não for suficiente, dê mais detalhes do seu problema.

Comment: Olá, Guilherme. Obrigado pela resposta.
Modifiquei um pouco o exemplo que você me enviou, agora ele está demonstrando a minha situação. 

http://jsfiddle.net/qGbw6/17/

O clique no botão só funciona na segunda vez, depois volta a funcionar corretamente.

Comment: Você só precisa executar a função `zoom()` para invocar as suas propriedades. [Clique aqui e entenda](http://jsfiddle.net/chiefGui/qGbw6/19/).

Comment: Entendi, no caso é necessário que a função pré-carregue antes de clicar no botão. Obrigado.

Comment: @Matheus Exato. ;)